# Sum profits of sales for every sale in SQLite using avg purchase price?

Tags: sqlite

In my SQLite database i have the following tables and data:

```
Products:
pro_id.  pro_name 
1.      Item1

Purchases:
pur_id  pro_id. pur_qty. pur_price
1.        1.        10.        10
2.        1.        10.        11
3.        1.        20.        10

Sales:
sa_id  pro_id   sa_qty   sa_price
1.      1.      10.     20
```

I calculated avg purchase price of item1 and it is: 10.25 so:

```
10 * 20 (sa_qty * sa_price) = 200
 - 
10 * 10.25 (sa_qty * avg_pur_price) = 102.5
= 97.5
```

that is profits that i am expecting (97.5) but instead I got 96.6667

This is the query that i tried:

```
select sa_id, sa_date, pro_name,
(sa_quantity * sa_price)
-
(sa_quantity
*
   (select avg(pur_price) from purchases where purchases.pro_id=products.pro_id))


as PROFIT

from products left join sales on sales.pro_id=products.pro_id group by sa_id having sa_id
```

Any idea? I appreciate any help

Comment: And how did you get 10.25 for avg_pur_price??? 10+11+10=31, 31/3=10.33333333